# Ensuring unique timestamps generation in asyncio/aiohttp coroutines

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm rewriting a web **scraper** with aiohttp. At some point, it has to make a POST request with a payload notably including a 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_ID'. These requests seem to always succeed, but they sometimes are redirected (302 status code) to another location, as additional details need to be fetched to be displayed on the page. Those redirections often fails ("A system error occurred" or "not authorized" error message is displayed on the page), and I don't know why.

I guess it's because they sometimes share the same value for 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_ID' (because headers and cookies are the same). Thus, I'd like to generate different timestamps in each request but I had no success doing that. I tried using some randomness with stuffs like asyncio.sleep(1+(randint(500, 2000) / 1000)). Also, note that doing the scraping with task_limit=1 succeeds (see code below).

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
async def search(Number, session):
    data = None
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    while data is None:
        t = int(round(time() * 1000)) #often got the same value here
        payload = {'Number': Number,
                   'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_ID': t}
        params = {'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_ID': t}
        try:
            async with session.post(SEARCH_URL, data=payload, params=params) as resp:
                resp.raise_for_status()
                data = await resp.text()
                return data
        except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
            print(f'Error with number{Number}: {e}')
```

It's called via:

```
async def main(username, password):
    headers = {'User-Agent': UserAgent().random}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        await login(session, username, password)
        """Perform the following operations:
        1. Fetch a bunch of urls concurrently, with a limit of x tasks
        2. Gather the results into chunks of size y
        3. Process the chunks in parallel using z different processes
        """
        partial_search = async_(partial(search, session=session)) #I'm using Python 3.7
        urls = ['B5530'] * 3 #trying to scrape the same URL 3 times
        results = await ( #I'm using aiostream cause I got a huge list of urls. Problem also occurs with gather. 
                stream.iterate(urls)
                | pipe.map(partial_search, ordered=False, task_limit=100)
                | pipe.chunks(100 // cpu_count())
                | pipe.map(process_in_executor, ordered=False, task_limit=cpu_count() + 1)
        )
```

Hope someone will see what I'm missing!

Comment: What are the requirements on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_ID?  Does it have to be an integer number of seconds?  Can it be floating point or integer value indicating nanoseconds since 1970 instead of seconds since 1970?

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that it indeed has to be an integer value. I believe it's generated with jQuery.now() when the user is navigating through his browser.

Comment: Does it have to reflect the actual current time?  Can we just set it to 1 for the first request, 2, 3, and so on?

Comment: I tried that, but it failed. I guess it has to reflects the current time. I'm starting to wonder if these timestamps really are causing the issue...

Comment: Maybe it's because you're making all the requests with a single session?  Have you tried creating a separate session for each thread?

Comment: I'm gonna try that, although I doubt the server will be happy with the same user login in 100 times from the same ip.

Comment: It's not clear that this question is aiohttp related. How did you generate `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_ID` in the previous version of your scraper?

Comment: @user4815162342 I did the same as here (`t = int(round(time() * 1000))`), but I associated a different session for each of my threads. I'm not sure the issue is session related though, as using 2 threads (and thus, 2 sessions) with the previous version of my script to get the same url 100 times never triggered the error.

Comment: Wait, your question says `t = int(round(time()))` but now this comment says `t = int(round(time() * 1000))`.  Which is it?

Comment: @JohnZwinck The last one : `int(round(time() * 1000))`. I changed the code a little for SO and did not pay attention. My bad.

Comment: @user4815162342 would you mind having a look at my script ? That may facilitate spotting the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how looking at the script would help. This question doesn't appear answerable in its current form. It's not about "ensuring unique timestamp generation" as indicated by the title (there is a number of ways to do that), it is about satisfying opaque requirements of a site your scraper is communicating with.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yeah you're right. I'll probably delete this question, as further investigations have shown that it may be an issue with the server itself or aiohttp not properly handling response headers ('Accept-Ranges': 'none' / 'x-old-content-length' of variable sizes and sometimes missing, 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'). If you have any clue about that...